# SQL GROUP BY not working

Tags: mysql, group-by

There are 4 different rows in the accounts table.

I can't figure out why my statement only returns 1 row.

```
SELECT *,
my_accounts.id as 'aid' 
FROM my_accounts 
LEFT JOIN my_availability on my_accounts.id = my_availability.the_account
LEFT JOIN my_reviews on my_accounts.id = my_reviews.the_reviewer
WHERE account_type = 1 
GROUP BY my_accounts.id
```

But when I remove the GROUP BY, I get 2 identical rows.

Example here: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6f2c

Comment: Show some sample data, Also you are using `*` so it will try to fetch data from all table.

Comment: A [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) would also be very helpful.

Comment: Why are you using `group by` in this query ?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6f2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use Group By for some **aggregate function**.Give in my_accounts.id two different values and see the results .According to you 
" when I remove the GROUP BY, I get 2 identical rows". Group By return one single   value when there is two identical values .In your  case it seems like in  my_accounts.id two values are same .

Answer (score 0):

turns out that it was the where clause for the acount_type causing my drama. I did instead find an aggregate solution